Finding antibodies sequence online
Not sure if this is the right section to ask this question but here we go.
I want to find human GPCR antibody sequences online and download them. I had some trouble finding good platforms with good filters and downloading the results.
How do you go about finding protein/antibody sequences online? Is there a universal database for proteins? Are there different smaller databases that specialize in antibodies?
How should I go about this?
Thank you!

I don't know for Abs but proteins can be found on several NCBI sites as well as SwissProt, PDB and quite a few others.

I would suggest looking here at the PLAbDAb database, this appears to be an up-to-date antibody database including sequences.
I ran a quick query for "GPCR" and got a number of results including protein sequences.
